# Image gallery for website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to make an image gallery that looks something like this website:

http://www.sandrageringinc.com/artists/nancy-dwyer/

currently I have achieved this:

http://port-80-rzczno273y.treehouse-app.com/

But I don't really know where to go next. I'm not fussed about styling as I can do that. Where I'm weak is in my functionality I just don't quite know what to do. Currently I've achieved to make the thumbnails fade into a bigger image when clicked. However I now want to be able to click the arrows and move to next picture in order of the thumbnails just like how the arrows work in the example
I posted at the top . Like I said previously I'm just not sure how to achieve this and I'm looking for direction or suggestions on how to achieve the result. Thank in advance for any help.

html code

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="gallery">
      <a href="img/large/dotted-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/dotted-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/gold-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/gold-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/purple-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/purple-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/dotted-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/dotted-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/gold-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/gold-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/purple-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/purple-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/dotted-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/dotted-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/gold-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/gold-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/purple-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/purple-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/dotted-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/dotted-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/gold-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/gold-small.jpg"</a>
      <a href="img/large/purple-large.jpg"><img src="img/small/purple-small.jpg"</a>
    </div>
    <div id="photo">
      <a class="next" href="#">&rarr;</a>
      <a class="prev" href="#">&larr;</a>

    </div>
  </div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
        //don't follow link
         evt.preventDefault();
         //get path to new image
       var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
         //get reference to old image
         var oldImage = $('#photo img');

             //create HTML for new image
             var newImage = $('<img src="' + imgPath +'">');
             //make new image invisible
             newImage.hide();
             //add to the #photo div
             $('#photo').prepend(newImage);
             //fade in new image
             newImage.fadeIn(1000);

             //fade out old image and remove from DOM
             oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
             $(this).remove();
                });      
    }); // end click

    $('#gallery a:first').click();
}); // end ready
```

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question, instead of asking us to debug an external website. Also, please be clear about errors you've gotten and how you tried to solve them.

Comment: Ok well my current code is

Answer (score 0):

If you are making just the same gallery why don't you just see the code of this gallery and find out how it works?

Seems http://www.sandrageringinc.com/artists/nancy-dwyer/ to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://prod-assets.exhibit-e.com/exhibit-e.com/js_libs/mootools/eE/Slideshow.js"></script>
```

on `div#slideshow`.

So just download this file and inspect how it works. It isn't even minified.

Or just use it as is on your site.